# Why does π-backbonding in a metal-carbonyl complex lead to a decrease in C-O bond strength?

Tags: bond, coordination-compounds, organometallic-compounds

I understand that π-backbonding in this complex involves the σ-donation of carbonyl to an empty d orbital of the metal, and the π-donation of the d electrons of the metal to the π* MO of the carbonyl. But why exactly does this lead to the weakening of the C-O bond (relative to free C-O)?

Comment: Do you know what a $\pi^*$ orbital is?

Comment: In simple words, the pi* orbital is antibonding in nature. So, putting electron density there will weaken the C-O pi bond. The CO bond contains both sigma and pi components. The pi component will be weakened.